# Better logic for testing string contents

Tags: python, coding-style, logic

I have a list of html elements that have some text.  I need to find the elements that have all the words I am going to supply.  I have some code that accomplished what I want but I am sure there is a better way to do this

```
myWords=['some', 'supplied','words']
theTextContents='a string that might or might not have all of some supplied words'
goodElements=[]
count=0
for word in myWords:
    if word in TheTextContents:
    count+=1
if count==len(myWords):
    goodElements.append(theTextContents)
```

There is a lot more code but this is the basic way we are testing to see if all of the words in MyWords are in theTextContent.  It seems to me that this is too clunky to be good Python code

Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if all(word in theTextContents.split() for word in myWords):
    ...
```

[`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) function in Python 2.5+

Comment: +1 but improve it: `all(word in theTextContents.split(' ') for word in myWords)`

Comment: @danihp: a good point, since that even fixes a possible bug in the original.

Comment: Thanks I did not know about all this is great

Answer (score 7):

```
if set(theTextContents.split()) >= set(myWords):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks this is very clean and useful, I would not have thought of this so I appreciate you taking the time to provide this answer

Comment: Most efficient according to `timeit` on OP's data.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
myWords=['some', 'supplied','words']
theTextContents='a string that might or might not have all of some supplied words'
goodElements=[]

splitted = theTextContents.split()
if all(word in splitted for word in myWords):
    goodElements.append(theTextContents)
```

Comment: +1 Splitting text outside the loop (generator expression) is good idea for performance.